# Windows TCP socket recv delay

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp

External controller sends 120-bytes message through TCP/IP socket every 30ms.
Application receives this messages through standard tcp/ip socket recv function.
It works perfectly under Linux & OSX (recv returns 120-bytes messages every 30ms).
Under Windows recv returns ~3500 bytes buffer about every 1 sec. Rest of time it returns 0. 
Wireshark under Windows shows messages indeed coming every 30ms.

How to make windows tcp socket work properly (without delay) ?

PS: I've played with TCP_NODELAY & TcpAckFrequency already. Wireshark shows everything is ok. So I think it's some Windows optimization, that should be turned off.

Reading--

```
int WMaster::DataRead(void)
{
if (!open_ok)  return 0;
if (!CheckSocket())
{
    PrintErrNo();
    return 0;
}
iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, (char *)input_buff,sizeof(input_buff),0);

nError=WSAGetLastError();
if(nError==0) return iResult;
if(nError==WSAEWOULDBLOCK) return iResult;

PrintErrNo();
return 0;
}
```

Initialization-

```
ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
ZeroMemory(&clientService, sizeof(clientService));
clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( deviceName.toLatin1().constData() );
clientService.sin_port = htons( port);

iResult = setsockopt(ConnectSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &flag, 
sizeof (int));

u_long iMode=1;
iResult=ioctlsocket(ConnectSocket,FIONBIO,&iMode);

iResult = ::connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, 
sizeof(clientService) );
```

CheckSocket -

```
bool WMaster::CheckSocket(void)
{
socklen_t len = sizeof (int);
int retval = getsockopt (ConnectSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*)(&valopt), &len );
if (retval!=0)
{
   open_ok=false;
   return false;
};
return true;
}
```

Comment: That's very odd.  Are you setting any other socket options on this socket?  SO_RCVLOWAT comes to mind, but that's documented as not-supported on Windows.  Also, you said recv() "returns 0" the rest of the time.  recv() would only return 0 if the socket was closed by the remote side - even if the socket was set to non-blocking.  Can you post the code that shows how you create and initialize the socket?

Comment: I added socket initializaion (iResult parsing was stripped)

Comment: Could you share your code that "loops" on calling recv? Your socket is non-blocking, and you aren't showing the code that calls select or waits for data to arrive. Also, you should only call WSAGetLastError if recv() returns SOCKET_ERROR. There's no guarantee that recv will set the error state back to 0 on a successful call.

Comment: Also, what sort of firewall and internet security software are you running? Those could interfere with socket operations. Check for installed Winsock LSPs and filter drivers that aren't from Microsoft. If in doubt, test on a clean machine.

Comment: I put DataRead function. It's called in thread loop with msleep(1). I see it's running about 120 times per sec. Just once a sec (about) it returns non-zero value.

I will try to call WSAGetLastError only if SOCKET_ERROR, but looks like calling it more often shouldn't be a problem.

I have no firewall installed. All Windows Firewall/security is turned off.

Comment: I formalized that into an answer below. Also, could you post the code to your CheckSocket function?

Comment: You could try removing CheckSocket. It doesn't do anything that couldn't be inferred from the return value of the recv() call and the subsequent WSAGetLastError.

Comment: I removed CheckSocket, call WSAGetLastError only if recv returns negative value. No results. I get the bug on Win7. A couple of WinXP machines work perfectly.

Comment: Read this link - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823764 - it's for send sockets, but it sounds very similar to yours.

Comment: I've seen this link. Controller sends 120 bytes which is less than TCPIP buffer. I played with TcpAckFrequency and buffer size, mentioned in this acticle. No results.

Comment: Did you play with SO_RCVBUF >

Comment: yes, I tested that buffer is 8k which is more than my 120 bytes message. I tried to set it to 256 bytes. No changes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider disabling the Nagle algorithm. 120-bytes is quite small and its possible that data is being buffered before being sent. Another reason I think it is the Nagle Algorithm is that about 33 sends should happen in 1 second. That corresponds with `33*120 = 3960 bytes / sec` very similar to the 3500 you are seeing.

Comment: I suppose Nable alghorithm can be turned off with TCP_NODELAY. I played with it - no results. As I told - wireshark shows communication with no delays.

Comment: It's a very good guess and might be the problem.  But I would figure Nagle algorithm only applies to the send side. Maybe it influence the ACKs being delayed by the receiver.

Comment: There is definetely no Nagle on the send side. Linux & OSX apps (receive side) work fine. Wireshark (Windows) on receive side tells there is no delay. Actually there was the ACK influence, wireshark showed it. After play with TcpAckFrequency 200ms delay is gone.

Comment: But the problem still here - messages coming every 30ms (Wireshark), recv returns all of them about once a second.

Comment: I very much doubt Nagle can be a possible cause, it delays _sending_ packets, but the OP already verified with Wireshark that packets _are arriving_ every 30ms.

Comment: yes, i told this. I think Windows socket do some optimization and accumulate very small messages in one package. The question is - how to turn OFF this optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Change your dataread function as follows such that WSAGetLastError is only called when there is an error.

```
int WMaster::DataRead(void)
{
  if (!open_ok)  return 0;
  if (!CheckSocket())
  {
      PrintErrNo();
      return 0;
  }
  iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, (char *)input_buff,sizeof(input_buff),0);
  if(iResult >= 0)
  {
      return iResult;
  }

  nError=WSAGetLastError();
  if(nError==WSAEWOULDBLOCK) return iResult;

   PrintErrNo();
   return 0;
}
```

The fact that you are polling the socket every millisecond may have something to do with your performance problem. But I'd like to see the source to CheckSocket before concluding that as the problem.

Comment: I put CheckSocket in the top

Comment: I checked with your fixes. The same result. I tried to remove CheckSocket() at all - the same.